# Baffling MySQL percentage calculation issue

Tags: mysql

I'm grouping some data and then trying to determine the percentage of each line out of the overall. So I wrote this:

```
select Vendor, OS_Version, count(distinct device_uid), (select count(distinct device_uid) from device_information_latest dil2 where dil1.vendor = dil2.vendor limit 1)    from device_information_latest dil1 where vendor in ('Canonical') GROUP BY Vendor, OS_Version   order by vendor, OS_Version;
```

Which gives me:

```
+-----------+------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Vendor    | OS_Version | count(distinct device_uid) | (select count(distinct device_uid) from device_information_latest dil2 where dil1.vendor = dil2.vendor limit 1) |
+-----------+------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Canonical | 14.04      |                          4 |                                                                                                              23 |
| Canonical | 16.04      |                         19 |                                                                                                              23 |
+-----------+------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

That looks right. Now, I try to divide the third column by the fourth (notice, I just replace the comma with a division slash).

```
select Vendor, OS_Version, count(distinct device_uid) / (select count(distinct device_uid) from device_information_latest dil2 where dil1.vendor = dil2.vendor limit 1)    from device_information_latest dil1 where vendor in ('Canonical') GROUP BY Vendor, OS_Version   order by vendor, OS_Version;

+-----------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Vendor    | OS_Version | count(distinct device_uid) / (select count(distinct device_uid) from device_information_latest dil2 where dil1.vendor = dil2.vendor limit 1) |
+-----------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Canonical | 14.04      |                                                                                                                                       0.0315 |
| Canonical | 16.04      |                                                                                                                                       0.1496 |
+-----------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you look at the value of the third column, you'd expect them to sum to 1.0 (100%). But they don't.

What am I missing?

Comment: *you'd expect them to sum to 1.0 (100%)* can you explain this ?

Comment: Exactly my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query looks good but I don't know exact structure of `device_information_latest`. What exactly is this `device_uid` field?

I propose to take a look at those wrong values. Let's suppose that `count(distinct device_uid)` always returns proper values 4 and 19. Then we can make two equations:

```
4 / x1 = 0.0315
19 / x2 =  0.1496
```

After making some calculations it turns out that:

```
x1 = 4 / 0.0315 = 126,984126984127
x2 = 19 / 0.1496 = 127,0053475935829
```

So in the first query `(select count(distinct device_uid) from device_information_latest dil2 where dil1.vendor = dil2.vendor limit 1)` was evaluated to 23 but in the second query it was evaluated to 127. Apparently, it matters whether you calculate two simple expressions in two different columns instead of one complex expression in one column. I suspect that somehow `where dil1.vendor = dil2.vendor` filters different rows, but it's just a guess. I'm not well versed in the order of SQL operations. Its logical order should be the same for both queries but some specific MySQL optimization might take place. Could you provide output of `EXPLAIN` for both queries?

Eventually, if this turned out to be some bug, you might just try this:

```
select
  Vendor,
  OS_Version,
  quantity/total as 'percentage'
from
(
  select 
    Vendor, 
    OS_Version, 
    count(distinct device_uid) as quantity, 
    (select count(distinct device_uid) from device_information_latest dil2 where dil1.vendor = dil2.vendor limit 1) as total
  from 
    device_information_latest dil1 
  where 
    vendor in ('Canonical') 
  GROUP BY 
    Vendor, OS_Version   
  order by vendor, OS_Version
) as tmp
```

Comment: Your query worked - I have no idea why though. Baffling.